# Error with arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, game-engine

Problem is that I want 'o' , not to repeat... I tried to find but I failed!
Also explain me that how this happens. I am a new learning programmer!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //all in-game variables here
    string o = "o";
    int oH = 0;
    int oW = 0;
    //variables ending point...

    bool run = true;
    bool frameShow = true;
    char input;
    int width = 53;
    int height = 22;

    string px[width][height];

    while (run)
    {
        for (int xEmp=0; xEmp<height;    xEmp++){
            for (int yEmp=0; yEmp<width; yEmp++) 
            {
                px[xEmp][yEmp]= " ";
            }

            if (frameShow)
            {
                clrscr();           // Must be at start

                px[oH][oW] = o;

                for (int x=0; x<height; x++)
                {
                    for (int y=0; y<width; y++)
                    {
                        cout << px[x][y];
                    }
                    cout << "\n";

                    frameShow = false;   // Must be at end
                }
            }

            if (kbhit())
            {
                input = getch();

                // Most Used ones are:
                // char 119 for "w"
                // char 97 for "a"
                // char 115 for "s"
                // char 100 for "d"
                // char 32 for "space"
                // char 27 for ESC

                if (input == 119)
                {
                    oH--;
                    frameShow = true;
                }
                else if (input == 115)
                {
                    oH++;
                    frameShow = true;
                }
                else if (input == 97)
                {
                    oW--;
                    frameShow = true;
                }
                else if (input == 100)
                {
                    oW++;
                    frameShow = true;
                }
                else if (input == 27)
                {
                    // Game exits...

                    // To terminate, use:
                    run = false;
                }

                if(oH > height)
                {
                    oH = height;
                }
                else if(oH < 0)
                {
                    oH = 0;
                }

                if(oW > width - 1)
                {
                    oW = width - 1;
                }
                else if(oW < 0)
                {
                    oW = 0;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    // Output for confiming program termination
    clrscr();
    cout << "\n  - Terminated! - \n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly - it's virtually unreadable at present.

Comment: Ok! But please help me, then...

Comment: Nope. Nope, nope, nope. Burn the code (salt the earth), fire your C++ teacher (or tutorial author), pick up a modern book and start over.

Comment: As a start, `width` and `height` are being changed. `px[width][height];`, `px[xEmp][yEmp]`, `xEmp<height`, `yEmp<width`

Comment: Bartak... I already know its really stupid code... but I don't understand that why 'o' is repeating! :/

Comment: Also `if(oH > height) { oH = height; }` is wrong. subtract ont from height.

Comment: Thanks t.pimentel! But I don't understand your first statement... Width and height are not 'being changed'. If so, how?

Comment: @t.pimentel, just tell me that why 'o' is repeating after definate intervals!

Comment: You have to print your output for us to examine it. Help us help you!

Comment: After pressing 's', three times, output is: o                              o                              o

Comment: o and then few spaces and then o again! :/ Every 's' as input, there is an increase of 'o' on output!

Comment: Added one more thing in my answer. Still has wrong brackets in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a start, `width` and `height` use is being changed. `px[width][height];`, `px[xEmp][yEmp]`, `xEmp<height`, `yEmp<width`. One time you use it as `px[width][height];`, then `px[height][width];`. keep your code coherent!

Also `if(oH > height) { oH = height; }` is wrong. subtract one from height.

This also probably doesn't do what you want:

```
for (int x=0; x<height; x++)
   for (int y=0; y<width; y++)
   {
       cout << px[x][y];
   }
   cout << "\n";
```

Use brackets correctly, IF you don't know how to use them, put them ALWAYS!

Again, I think you're not using brackets correctly:

```
for (int xEmp=0; xEmp<height;    xEmp++){
    for (int yEmp=0; yEmp<width; yEmp++) 
    {
        px[xEmp][yEmp]= " ";
    }
... // do other things
}
```

I think you want to close it right away to set everything back to space and them do other works. As it is now, it will set one line back to spaces, print everything and run your code, and only after empty next line.

```
for (int xEmp=0; xEmp<height;    xEmp++){
    for (int yEmp=0; yEmp<width; yEmp++) 
    {
        px[xEmp][yEmp]= " ";
    }
}
... // do other things
```

Ps: `clrscr()` is a non-standard function, only works in Windows, I think, for Linux use `system('clr');`

Ps2: Why are you using `std::string` instead of char if you only store chars?

Comment: Wow! It fixed all... Extremely thank you! My relatives are criticizing me that your codes are nothing but a garbage and I got very depressed! Now, it looks like t.pimentel's answer wake me up... Simple mistakes are sometimes hard to find as I am pondering on it for over 1 hour! Lesson here, is "Keep the order!". Thanks!

Comment: No problems. To make debugging easier try to print some variables here and there to analyse what's happening. Ps: Please set answer as correct. Ps2: Upvote it. Ps3: Try to use better variable names `px` doesn't mean anything, maybe `gameMap`, instead of `o`, maybe `oSymbol`.

Comment: yeah! You are right! Actually, I am programming in my phone using an app called C4droid (andriod OS). The 53 and 22 characters completely filled my screen in right manner and when we press 'w' or 's', it looks like as if the o moves down in correct way... For other OS, just add a new line after every 53 characters. That is why it looks crappy. Also, how can I do this thing? And yes, I want to make 'space' exactly after every 'frame' so that o don't get more in amount. I am not using Linux as I mentioned before. Ps2 answer : User also have to input name in some part of it (future)

Comment: Its just a try! I often use such variables as you mentioned... Also, next time if I ask a question, it will have understandable variables...